# CSS using first-child and before

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have div structure as follows

```
<div class="section-outer"> 
  <div class="section-inner">
      <div class="type-1"> Hi </div>
      <div class="type-2">sub contents 1</div>              
      <div class="type-2">sub contents 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to add some content before the text "sub content 1" and for which I use below CSS.

```
.section-outer .section-inner > div.type-2:first-child:before {
  content: "SOME CONTENT";
}
```

But the above css selector is not selecting any div. Can anyone please help me.

Comment: div.type-2 is not a first-child. That's why your selector is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:first-child` pseudo class selects the element that is the 1st child element of its container. `.type-2:first-child` selects nothing, because none of the divs with `type-2` class is the first child of `.section-inner`. There is `:nth-match(1)` selector in CSS Selectors level 4 draft, but no current browser supports it, unfortunately.

You can use a workaround like this:

```
.section-outer .section-inner > div.type-2:before {
  content: "SOME CONTENT";
}

.section-outer .section-inner > div.type-2 ~ div.type-2:before {
  content: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because `div.type-2` is **not** the *first child* of its parent (`.section-inner` element).

From the **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child)**:

> The `:first-child` CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the
>   first child element of its parent.

[`selector:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child) represents the first child element of its parent matching the `selector`, and in your case the first child element of the `.section-inner` is `div.type-1` not `div.type-2`.

In other words, `:first-child` pseudo-class looks through the children tree of the parent in order to select the first child, not through a list of `element.class`.

---

In this particular instance you could use [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `+` in order to select the first `div.type-2` as follows:

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/xopox/1/edit)**.

```css
.section-inner > div.type-1 + div.type-2:before {
  content: "SOME CONTENT";
}
```

`div.type-1 + div.type-2` selector will select the `div.type-2` element which immediately follows the `div.type-1`.

---

The above assumes `.type-1` and `.type-2` are not repeated frequently. If this is not the case, you could use [general sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) `~` in order to override the `content` property as follows:

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/xopox/2/edit)**.

```css
.section-inner > div.type-2 ~ div.type-2:before {
  content: none;
}
```

It's worth noting that adjacent/general sibling selectors [are supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors#Browser_compatibility) [in **IE7+**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

you can as well use the `nth-child()` selector :

```
.section-inner div:nth-child(2):before  {
    content:'second element is a div';
}
.section-inner div.type-2:nth-child(2):before  { 
    content:'second element is a div and has class type-2';
}
.section-inner :nth-child(2):before  { 
    content:'any second element';
}
```